# How is this blur effect done in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects, motion-blur

http://wowslider.com/jquery-image-rotator-terse-blur-demo.html

I can't find any blur-related CSS 3 property. And they don't appear to be using Flash..

Comment: Did you even look at the source?  I saw this right at the top in the title tag - *jQuery Image Rotator Terse Blur Demo : jQuery Banner Rotator*.  Looks like... they use a feature of jquery.

Comment: yes, [this](http://wowslider.com/images/demo/terse-blur/engine1/wowslider.js) is the source, I can't understand much of it though..

Comment: It looks like it's using `canvas`. It could be doing that for the blur effect.

Comment: @thelolcat: If you can't understand it then perhaps you should be studying the fundamentals a bit more.

Comment: @EdS.: That doesn't tell you how the blur works.

Comment: The actual blurring logic appears to be in [this file](http://wowslider.com/images/demo/terse-blur/engine1/script.js).

Comment: the browser start to lag rly bad when viewing it :s

Comment: @SLaks: Sure it does.  Here is the JS source: http://wowslider.com/images/demo/terse-blur/engine1/wowslider.js  It's from wowslider.com, so... start looking there.

Comment: @EdS: That doesn't really help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're drawing on HTML5's `<canvas>`, not CSS3.

Reference: http://www.flother.com/blog/2010/image-blur-html5-canvas/